# What stops us from running multiple applications on the same server?

Tags: docker, server, containers, virtual-machine, virtualization

When reading about docker, I came to know that earlier IT companies used to run single app per server and since they didn't knew how large the application would scale, they bought over performing servers which run at a fraction of their potential capacity resulting in waste of the resources and money.

But I wonder, what stopped them from running multiple application on the same server? Why a server cannot run multiple applications with time sharing of its resources just like our personal computers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With docker, you typically make smaller and more specific services. The containerization of them makes them easier to scale, and you are sort of guided into designing systems differently to accommodate these properties.

It is not uncommon to compose several docker images and containers to replace the function of a single old-school service.

The services of yesteryear were big, with a lot of moving parts, resource-hungry dependencies and you had to scale your hardware to serve the peak resource draw of your system. Meaning, if you had a certain day of the month where you had to process millions of requests, even though you only had to serve a couple of hundred for the remaining days, meant you had to run the service on hardware capable of serving at that peak level at any given time. Running several services on the same node would put you at risk of having an outage on the important peak periods. Which is one reason single responsibility servers would be employed.

This is only one of the reasons, other reasons that added to the benefit of running one app per node are maintenance, deployability, and development. For instance, if you are running multiple applications on one node when you have to take that node down for maintenance, well now your entire system is down. And you have lost your ability to handle that situation gracefully. When it comes to deployment, well configuring multiple applications on one machine can get pretty complex. You risk disrupting the entire system if something goes wrong, and it is hard to automate. Because you will have to make sure you are not corrupting the state of another running application on the same machine. Remember DLL-hell on Windows? It was not uncommon for having two applications using the same component with a different version to disrupt each other at runtime because of incompatibility between the two versions. A single application per box mitigates that risk. And if you are developing using multiple teams, well then you can have them work independently of each other if the teams have separate infrastructures.

Now, something new came along and changed how we spread our applications across the network. Virtualization made it easier to utilize the hardware more efficiently. Instead of spreading our applications across multiple physical servers, we would model the same structure using virtual machines running on the same machine. These machines would be true beasts compared to the previous servers, but the combined cost would be significantly less, not to mention the maintenance requirements would be significantly lower.

Now, with time this approach grew into containers. Where you not only spread your applications across the same piece of hardware, you spread your tasks within that application as well. This combined with using the bare minimum of your runtime environment resources like you only bring the portion of your OS that you need to function, well you can build many super light-weight purpose-built tiny applications. The separation of different applications on different machines drove this innovation towards single-responsibility functions that can be run, scaled, destroyed, developed, maintained, and life-cycled independently of each other.